# Bamboo NuGet Restore command is running older version of SDK

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a .net core 2.2 web app that has been building successfully in Bamboo for several months. Recently someone rebuilt the new Bamboo server (we're on premise, not in cloud) as the first step in a Bamboo upgrade and my build began failing. The error is:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.509\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2.

My original post incorrectly asserted that this error was occurring in a Script task running dotnet publish. I realize now that it is actually occurring in the previous task - a Bamboo Command task running NuGet Restore. And I can reproduce the problem at the command line, so it does not appear to be a Bamboo issue.

So, in summary, I have a .NET Core solution with four projects. All four projects target .NET Core 2.2. I have NuGet 5.3.1 installed on my Bamboo build server. I navigate to the solution directory and run

> nuget restore

And I first get the following informational message:

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.9.21.664' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.

Followed by four instances of the following error, one per project:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.509\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2.

What is causing the nuget restore operation to be working with .NET Core 2.1 instead of 2.2? Is there a problem with the msbuild auto-detection?

I initially found that .net core 2.2 had not been installed on the new server, so I installed it, so both are now installedre. But the error above persists and continues to reference .net core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `nuget restore` use `dotnet restore`.

A cleaner way to set this up would be to configure a dotnet executable as a Command in Bamboo.  By doing this you can ensure that you are running the correct executable every time.  Additionally you will gain the following benefits:

- The command will show what version it is
- This scale to other build agents
- Adds clarity to the Bamboo task (will show as dotnet 2.2 instead of a script).

Then you can have dedicated tasks for each step (e.g., restore, build, test)

Comment: Sorry. I realize, in retrospect, that my original post was in error. I've edited it significantly. The main point is that it is not the Script task with the dotnet publish command that is failing. It is the prior task - a Command task running NuGet Restore. You can get additional details in my updated original post.